# How to create a gradient colour like on the picture and the apply it on a mesh

Tags: materials, shaders

I am making a logo like on the picture with blender , but the colour of the text doesn't come up as it should be .

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You may achieve it using the ***Gradient Texture*** and ***Color Ramp*** nodes. 
[image]

Set up the *material nodes* as pictured below.
[image]

You may also add a ***Mapping Node*** to change the location, rotation or scale of a gradient.
[image]

Try to change the ***Gradient Texture***'s type to for example ***Radial***, ***Diagonal*** or ***Quadratic Sphere*** and experiment with a ***Mapping node*** and ***Color Ramp*** settings for different results.
[image]
[image]
[image]

You may also add a ***Bright/Contrast*** node between *Color Ramp* and *Diffuse* nodes to make some quick color adjustments.

Here's a .blend file with the closest effect to the reference you provided: [image]

Answer (score 4):

- You can achieve this by mixing a bunch of **Diffuse Shader Nodes** and connecting them to a couple of **Mix Shader Nodes**, while using **Voronoi Texture** as a *Factor* of those Mix Shader Nodes.

Here is the Node set up:
[image]

And Here is the Result:
[image]

- The second way to do that would be to UV project from view the letters and then export the UV layout to an external photo editing software like Gimp or Photoshop and create your self the Gradient Texture that will lie uppon the letters. Then import this texture to Blender and use it as a *Factor* of **Mix Shader Nodes** mixing different **Diffuse Shader Nodes**.

  - The third way could be for you to UV project the letters UV layout as before and import it in to an external Photo Editing software, create whole the gradient texture there and then just add it to the letters, to the color of the **Emission Shader Node**.

Comment: I am a little paranoid about your spelling of Voronoi.  In any case ochen xoroshow.