# Gradient color in blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

I want the color of my object look like the photo above. I have tried many ways i saw in youtube but none of them worked can anyone show me how?
[image]

i made texture here but i don't know how to assign it
It actually worked in blender cycles thanks 
But why when I shift to blender render I see white ??

Comment: Related answers (but using Cycles): http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22929/how-to-create-a-gradient-texture , http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36734/how-to-create-a-gradient-colour-like-on-the-picture-and-the-apply-it-on-a-mesh

Answer (score 7):

In *Edit Mode* unwrap the mesh (select the whole mesh with <kbd>A</kbd>, then press <kbd>U</kbd>-->*Project From View*).
[image]

Add a new material and go to *Texture* header. Add a new texture, set its *Type* to ***Blend***. In *Blend* panel click the ***Vertical*** button. You may also change the *Progression* type to ***Easing*** for smoother colors transition.
[image]